# Basic question about loops in mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, procedural-programming

I am very new to *Mathematica* programming and am trying to find the optimum of a numerical integral for various values of a parameter.  Here is the basic code for one parameter value that runs fine - I have defined a list of values for the parameter, p2g:

```
cl = 0;
ch = 1;
el = -.1;
eh = .1;
F[e_] = Max[0, Min[(e - el)/(eh - el), 1]];
d = .1;
pi = .2;
p2g = .05 Array[# &, 6];
p1sg = ConstantArray[0, 6];
i = 1;
Obj1[p_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[(c + d - p) (1 - F[(1 - pi) p2g[[i]] + pi c - p]), {c, 
 cl, p2g[[i]]}] + 
NIntegrate[(c + d - p) (1 - F[c - p]), {c, p2g[[i]], ch}];
p1s = p /. Last[NMaximize[{Obj1[p]}, {p}]];
p1sg[[i]] = p1s;
```

My naive way of doing this was to put the whole thing in a for loop and change $ i$. Once I do this, the code returns an error. basically it cannot assign the value in NMaximize. Does anyone know how to deal with this.

Thanks.

Comment: See the preferred function:  `Table`.  Also, your code simply cannot run because it has several syntax errors, for instance missing semicolons at the end of every line.  Also, please show *all* necessary code, such as your definitions of `F`, `p2g`, etc.

Comment: When using `NIntegrate`, one must assign numerical values to all quantities.  Here, `pi` and `p2g` are undefined.  This needs to be corrected.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention that `pi` and `p2g` are defined before

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete code that can be copied and executed by readers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: ok posted the full code without the for loop. This code runs fine. When I put the part following 'i=1;' in a `for` loop is where the problems come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal change to the code produces results.

```
l = 0;
ch = 1;
el = -.1;
eh = .1;
F[e_] = Max[0, Min[(e - el)/(eh - el), 1]];
d = .1;
pi = .2;
p2g = .05 Array[# &, 6];
p1sg = ConstantArray[0, 6];
Do[
  Obj1[p_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[(c + d - p) (1 - F[(1 - pi) p2g[[i]] + pi c - p]), {c, 
      cl, p2g[[i]]}] + 
    NIntegrate[(c + d - p) (1 - F[c - p]), {c, p2g[[i]], ch}];
p1s = p /. Last[NMaximize[{Obj1[p]}, {p}]];
p1sg[[i]] = p1s, {i, 6}];

p1sg
(* {0.104881, 0.118322, 0.13784, 0.161245, 0.187083, -1.23481} *)
```

`Table`, as suggested above by [David G. Stork](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9735/david-g-stork), also works.

```
Obj2[i_, p_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(c + d - p) (1 - F[(1 - pi) p2g[[i]] + pi c - p]), {c, 
     cl, p2g[[i]]}] + 
   NIntegrate[(c + d - p) (1 - F[c - p]), {c, p2g[[i]], ch}];
Table[p /. Last[NMaximize[{Obj2[i, p]}, {p}]], {i, 6}]
```

producing the same results.

Comment: Great thanks a lot @bbgodfrey. Still puzzling to me why 'for' didn't work. I tried 'While' and that had the same issue. Also how would you do this in `Table`? Sorry I am pretty new to mathematica - mainly a matlab coder.

Comment: Fantastic @bbgodfrey. Thanks very much